# How Can I Set SL and TP?

Tags: pine-script

i have strategy for entry and my stop loss is low of before candle.
and my tp is R/R 3 that it set according to Stoploss.

i wrote code but it not work.

```
strategy.entry("Long Position",strategy.long,when = LongEntry)
strategy.exit("Exit Long" , from_entry = "Long Position" , stop = low[1] , profit = 3*low[1] )
```

what is problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you will be updating your stop loss and take profit prices on every bar as it is written in your example. Because, with every new bar, there will be a new `low` value. And with every new bar, your `strategy.exit()` function will be called.

What you can do is, store the `low` price at the time of the entry and use it in your `strategy.exit()` call.

```
var float low_at_entry = na

if (LongEntry)
    low_at_entry := low

strategy.entry("Long Position",strategy.long,when = LongEntry)

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit("Exit Long" , from_entry = "Long Position" , stop = low_at_entry [1] , profit = 3*low_at_entry [1] )
```

**Note:** You need to make sure that your `LongEntry` is true only once during a trade. Otherwise `low_at_entry` will be updated after the entry again.

Comment: thank you for your answer. the stoploss work but take profit not work. i test it in one example. the entry point is 1.00283. the sl put in low of before candle that was 1.00272 and it was true. but tp put in 1.00287 that was make R/R 0.36 and was wrong. what is solution for tp?

Comment: nobody want to answer??